# Insert object to nsmutable array at index dynamicly is not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add a `URL` to every fifth row of the array, but for some weird reason this is not working.

**This** works, and I want to make this dynamically.

```
self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: 0);
self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: 5);
self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: 10);
self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: 15);
self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: 20);
self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: 25);
```

**The array:**

```
var tableData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

The loop I tried and in my eyes should work.

```
for(var i = 0; i < (tableData.count + 3); i += 1) {
      if(i % 5 == 0){
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
           {
             self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: i);
           }
       }

}
```

The error:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index (26) beyond bounds (24)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @patrick and @chronikum say, your index, or `i` runs "over the edge"

Your problem lies here:

`for(var i = 0; i < (tableData.count + 3); i += 1)`

If you have 24 elements in your `tableData` then you actually loop over 3 elements that are not there. That would work if you don't actually do anything in your loop.

But when you say:

`self.tableData.insertObject(url!, atIndex: i);`

and `i` is larger than `tableData.count`, then you are trying to insert something into `tableData` at a position that isn't there (26 in this case, in an array that holds 24 elements).

I don't know if this does what you'd like, but a simple fix would be to just run to the end of `tableData`, so you could change your for loop to:

`for(var i = 0; i < (tableData.count); i += 1)`

And if you'd like to do this more "Swifty" then maybe you could look at the `enumerate` function as described in [The Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) (search for "Iterating Over an Array")

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The Index is not in the array.count range.

Answer (score 3):

Array have 24 items and you are trying obtain the item number 26. It is not possible.